# Make table columns resizable with jQuery plugin

Tags: jquery, datatables, reactjs

I use DataTables and [jquery-resizable-columns](https://github.com/dobtco/jquery-resizable-columns) to create table with resizable columns. Here is [example](http://jsfiddle.net/1ymqr2ns/10/).

I tried to use jquery-resizable-columns plugin in basic ReactJS application with DataTables. I added *resizableColumns* function in *componentDidMount*, but it doesn't work.

I am in ReactJS, can anybody explain to me why it doesn't work?

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/14044/)

**jsx script**

```
/** @jsx React.DOM */

var TodoApp = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {items: [], text: ''};
  },
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h3>React + jQuery.DataTable</h3>

        <LopMonHoc />
      </div>
    );
  }
});

var LopMonHoc = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function(){
        return {data: []}
    },
    componentDidMount: function(){
        var self = this;
        $('#mytable').DataTable({
          "bAutoWidth": false,
          "bDestroy": true,     
          "fnDrawCallback": function() {                
                self.forceUpdate();         
          }, 
        });
        $("#mytable").resizableColumns();
    },
    componentDidUpdate: function(){
        $('#mytable').DataTable({
          "bAutoWidth": false,
          "bDestroy": true, 
        });
    },
    render: function(){
        var x = [];

        x.push(
            <tr><td>zaxs</td><td>hello</td><td>xzc</td></tr>
        )

        x.push(
            <tr><td>hello</td><td>wef</td><td>qw</td></tr>
        )

        x.push(
            <tr><td>wefwe</td><td>fgn</td><td>asc</td></tr>
        )

        return (
            <div className="table-responsive">
                <h4>Hello</h4>
                <table className="table table-bordered" id="mytable">
                    <thead>
                        <tr className="success">
                            <td>col1</td>
                            <td>col2</td>
                            <td>col3</td>
                        </tr>   
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        {x}
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        )       
    }
 });

React.render(<TodoApp />, document.body);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The nice thing about ReactJS and the whole node ecosystem is that someone else out there has done the work and turned into a plugin/module. Here is something that will be of use to you: [colresizable](https://www.npmjs.com/package/colresizable). The nice thing about this is that you won't have to manage where to put things for each component and it does what you want and more...

You need to add this to the end of your `componentDidUpdate` method...

```
$(function(){$("#mytable").colResizable();});
```

You had:

```
... 
componentDidMount: function(){
    var self = this;
    $('#mytable').DataTable({
      "bAutoWidth": false,
      "bDestroy": true,     
      "fnDrawCallback": function() {                
            self.forceUpdate();         
      }, 
    });
    $("#mytable").colResizable();
},
componentDidUpdate: function(){
    $('#mytable').DataTable({
      "bAutoWidth": false,
      "bDestroy": true, 
    });
},
...
```

You need to change to this:

```
...
componentDidMount: function(){
    var self = this;
    $('#mytable').DataTable({
      "bAutoWidth": false,
      "bDestroy": true,     
      "fnDrawCallback": function() {                
            self.forceUpdate();         
      }, 
    });
},
componentDidUpdate: function(){
    $('#mytable').DataTable({
      "bAutoWidth": false,
      "bDestroy": true, 
    });
    $(function(){$("#mytable").colResizable();});
},
...
```

I just tested it on jsfiddle link you provided and was able to resize the columns.

Comment: I tried coresizable plugin, but it doesn't work. https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/14047/

Comment: Make sure to mark the answer correct, I am going to update it in a sec.

Comment: `$(function(){$("#mytable").colResizable();});` can be replaced with `$("#mytable").colResizable();`

Answer (score 0):

There is [ColReorderWithResize](https://github.com/jeffreydwalter/ColReorderWithResize) plug-in that adds ability reorder and resize columns for the latest version of jQuery DataTables 1.10.

You need to include the appropriate JS file and use the following initialization code.

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    'dom': 'Rlfrtip'
});
```

See [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/gyrocode/m55rnu7j/) for code and demonstration.

See [jQuery DataTables: Column reordering and resizing](https://www.gyrocode.com/articles/jquery-datatables-column-reordering-and-resizing/) for more details.