# How to resize columns using jquery datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using jquery datatable and I want to resize columns, does anyone here have any idea how to do it?

```
 var table= $('#example').DataTable( {
                destroy: true,
                "aaData":data,


                "order": [[1, 'asc']]
            } );
```

Comment: View columndef in official documentation of datatables. It have width property

Comment: i cant make them resizable..??

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/32072715/3022349 use colresizable

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Make table columns resizable with jQuery plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32072715/make-table-columns-resizable-with-jquery-plugin)

Comment: I don't try it yet. But there is a legacy plugin for DataTables v1.9 that might still work http://legacy.datatables.net/extras/thirdparty/ColReorderWithResize/

Answer (score 0):

```
var table= $('#example').DataTable( {
                destroy: true,
                "aaData":data,


                "order": [[1, 'asc']]
            } );
table.columns.adjust().draw();
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**: after OP clarified that he wants users to be able to resize columns, I commented that the DataTables plugin itself does not bring that functionality. He could, however, use a third party plugin to get that functionality to work - there might be version conflicts due to most of the available plugins being outdated: [plugin](https://github.com/dobtco/jquery-resizable-columns)

You can pass in a `columnDefs` array into your `DataTable()`-call:

```
$('#table').DataTable({
    columnDefs: [
        {
            targets: [5],
            width: "8%",
        },
    ],
});
```

where `targets:` is an array of column indexes, starting with 0.

To target multiple columns you could do something like this:

```
columnDefs: [
    {
        targets: [5],
        width: "8%",
    },
    {
        targets: [0, 1],
        width: "11%",
    },
    {
        targets: [2, 3],
        width: "30%",
    },
],
```

For further read on `columnDefs` as well as available options, check out the [documentation](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columnDefs).

Comment: it gives only 8% but it doesnt resize

Comment: What do you mean by that?

Comment: i want to make the columns resizable

Comment: The DataTables-plugin itself doesn't bring that functionality as of now. You can use a plugin to implement the functionality - the plugins I found, however, are mostly outdated but might still work: [plugin](https://github.com/dobtco/jquery-resizable-columns).

Answer (score 0):

You can adjust using columns property,

```
var table= $('#example').DataTable( {
                    destroy: true,
                    "aaData":data,      
                     "order": [[1, 'asc']],
                     "columns": [{ "width": "20%" },
                        null // depends upon columns you have 
                          ]
                } );
```

refer link for more description https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.width